# Is the M.SE blog dead?

Tags: support, blog

I was thinking of writing a post for the blog, and [found the FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13903/community-blog-faq). It links to a blog chat room which is dead, and it is entirely unclear whom to contact about writing posts.

Comment: Link to the blog: http://math.blogoverflow.com/

Comment: ... someone just thawed the [frozen heart (chattoom)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14206/the-blog-room).

Comment: I have a vague memory of earning the right to say "I told you so" right now.

Comment: Oh yeah, [that was my reaction nearly four years ago](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/does-our-site-need-a-blog-like-a-few-sites-on-the-network-have#comment15640_4129).

Comment: I don't think most users are even aware that a blog exists. Its only sign of existence on main is a temporary entry (when there's a new post and when it was announced) in the "Featured" box in the sidebar -- you know, the one that looks like an ad and that most people ignore. The submission process is also rather obscure and one must jumps through a few hoops to even find the FAQ from the blog's main page (I don't think a link buried in a paragraph in the "about" page is sufficient...).

Comment: A link to the blog appears under the "Stack Exchange" pull-down menu on the upper left in main and in meta.

Comment: It's at least as well-publicized on the page as chat and Meta. But chat and meta ore more likely to be used.

Comment: Users are directed to meta when their questions get closed, by other users in the comments, from the help pages... The use of meta is completely transparent for someone who knows how to use the main site, whereas the publication process for the blog is more involved. Same for chat: mentioned in the help pages, the system automatically redirects you there for long discussions, very easy to use for any user. Besides, it take significantly more efforts to produce a blog post than it takes to ask a question on meta. Now combine the two effects.

Comment: @Najib: I feel that this is not the issue. We could have had more active threads on meta inviting people to publish, raising awareness as to how to do that, and that it's even a "thing" to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it actually dead? There hasn't been activity on it for 7 months. But it's not so dead yet that we've removed it.

So the short answer is **no, it's not technically dead.** (Although it's unclear if it has a pulse).

The liveliness of the blog feeds on itself, I think. An active blog has more presence and solicits more contributors than an inactive blog. If you have something you would like to contribute, I recommend going for it. If you have a blog, it's also fine to post both on your private blog and on the Math Community Blog.

If you would like to contribute a post, you can use the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14206/the-blog-room) (which I've unfrozen). Alternately, I've handled most (but not all) additions to the blog, and you can just get in contact with me.

To contribute, you must first log into the blog once (this needs to be done only once). Then you need to ask one of the site moderators to give you draft access (usually through the chat room). Then you write a post, and notify the site moderators (also usually through the chat room) that you're done. Every thing that gets here gets read by a few people before being officially posted.

In the past, there were a few community members who stepped forward to be maintainers of the blog. But I'm hazarding a guess to say that after so many months of inactivity, sticking with the site mods would be your best bet for now.

Comment: The main reason I called it dead was the lack of activity, and the lack of the chat room.